# \mathit only works with preview mode?

Tags: support, mathjax

Earlier I added an example to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but it seems that `\mathit` only works in preview. Is there any suitable alternative?

[image]

**Update: as quid suggested this is likely a rendering issue and the actual rendering does not follow order of the actual content**

Comment: On the update, also note that mathbb does not render. I believe that MathJax renders in more than one step. In the initial rendering some things are not done, and somehow it does not seem to get to the latter steps in that thread on some devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be no need for an alternative.

$\mathit{It \ does \ work}$, at least for me.

It does take a while to render though and in between it looks plain;
that the thread there is so complex might make it take a long time.

Let me add some other things $\mathbb{ABC}$, $\mathcal{ABC}$.

For an alternative, it depends a bit on the intended use case. Honestly, I do not see much point for it, as variables are usually slanted anyway $ABC$.

Comment: I think you are right that it is a rendering issue. It is just not obvious because the styling is applied after other content/styling has been loaded (or perhaps the particular styling failed to render)

Comment: The italics is used for formatting text strings, at least that was I had been looking for the other time.

Comment: If you want to format text in a formula it is better to use `$\textit{like this}$` $\textit{like this}$; if it is outside it is done with mark down `*like this*` *like this*

Comment: I think it was because I wanted to mix italics and normal text in some annotation, so I was looking for the MathJax equivalent for that.

Comment: Regarding the rendering, my phone does not manage to render it in the other thread, but does manage to do it here. It really ought to be a technical issue with  how MJ is rendered and large threads. (It's not specific to mathit, it's the same with some other fonts there.)

Comment: Eventually my phone managed; it really just seems an issue of "takes a long time" and/or "sometimes hangs" and not something fundamental.